# Flipping Subviews in a Container View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am having difficulties with flipping two subviews in my iOS application. The way it's setup is that I created a view in my interface file. When the view loads, View 1 should appear in that view (achieved by using `addSubview`). When a button is pressed on View1, it should flip around to reveal view2.

From various questions in StackOverflow, I implemented the following Code:

```
-(void)LetUsFlip
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:_containerView cache:YES];

    if ([self.view1 superview])
   {
        NSLog(@"Show View 2");
        [view1 removeFromSuperview];
        [_containerView addSubview:view2];
        [_containerView sendSubviewToBack:view1];
   }
   else
   {
        NSLog(@"Show View 1");
        [view2 removeFromSuperview];
        [_containerView addSubview:view1];
        [_containerView sendSubviewToBack:view2];
   }

   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

When I run this code, the first flip animation works fine, i.e., View 2 is shown on button press. But when I press the button in View 2 again, the animation happens and View 1 is **not** shown - Gives a blank screen.
Both the buttons on View1 and View2 respectively call the above method. The NSLog also works exactly the way the it should but am having issues with animation.

Thanks.

Comment: How are `view1` and `view2` declared? Weak, strong?

Comment: Hey zoul , It's declared as: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *view1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `view1` something other than `nil` during the second transition? It’s stored in a weak property, which means it could get deallocated as you remove it from its superview. Try changing the property declaration to `strong` and see if that helps.